# How to connect the current user and the user of a web application using htpasswd in python?

Tags: python

I have a python script which is using htpasswd authentication. I wish to modify the script depending on the user who has logged in currently. This application is web-enabled. eg.

```
if current_username = 'ABC':
   m = 2 
elif current_username = 'PQE':   
   m = 4
else:      
   m = 6
```

Any of the user can log in any time / simultaneously. Want the simplest and most efficient solution. Can anybody help? **How do I know which of the user has logged in at any point of time? import getpass  getpass.getuser() in the script** ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to retrieve a value for specific usernames, you could use a dictionary to store the mapping between username and value. For example, your code above could be rewritten:

```
username_mapping = {"ABC": 2, "PQE": 4}
# The second argument to get will be returned if the key could not be found
# in the dictionary
m = username_mapping.get(current_username, 6)
```

For a larger system, you might want to look into a distributed key value store (redis would be a good place to start).